# My B2C Custom Attributes are not Saving

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm passing in custom attributes via JWT to my sign-up policies but the attributes are not persisting/saving.

I've verified I'm sending the values in the JWT.

I've temporarily displayed the values on the signup page and I'm seeing them.

I've verified the Technical Profile that saves the custom attributes to AD.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, I renamed the attribute, `extension_helloWorld` to `extension_HelloWorld`, and that use-case is not supported.  Apparently, you **can't** just **change** the **casing** of a custom attribute.

I had to [delete the custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/extensionproperty-delete) and then it started saving!  FYI, I used the [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#) to delete the attribute.